# Issue with a shader on Minecraft - can't get rid of it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So as others on here have, I clicked on the super secret settings button in minecraft and my screen got all messed up. I clicked <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and restarted my game but the screen still looks messed up. I clicked <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and it says I have no shaders on. Now when I click on the super secret settings button, it overlays a random shader on top of the one that's stuck on my game. How do I put my screen back to normal if it thinks it is normal?

Heres a screenshot to show that my screen is messed up but it doesn't show any shaders:[image: no shaders (but there is????)]

And here is where I clicked the button again and now two shaders are stacked:
[image: literally what is happening]

Someone help this is really messing my game up and making it impossible to play.

Comment: I tried uninstalling Minecraft and reinstalling it but that did nothing and the screen is still messed up

Answer (score 1):

You've probably turned on the 3D view mode, specifically the anaglyphic option.

You can turn it off in options->graphics (from memory, at work so can't verify).